# Why is data in my tab bar view not up to date?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar controller with three tabs. Tab number two has a view containing two UILabel views. These are bound via InterfaceBuilder to IBOutlets in the view's controller.

It can happen that I set values to these labels before the user taps on tab bar item #2, hence before the view is loaded. What happens is that the view then only displays the default data setup with Interface Builder.
How can I make sure the data is up to date either by forcing the view to load when the tab bar controller starts up or maybe by configuring somehting in outlets which I missed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go it : simply put the IB stuff in the same NIB file and it won't happen